# AppStore in iPhone Simulator Xcode

Tags: ios, simulator

Is it possible to download and run apps from the iPhone AppStore in Xcode iPhone simulator ? I would download Xcode for my Mac and use it as a iPhone then ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, the simulator runs i386 binaries and iPhone appstore apps are ARM binaries apps.

iOS apps are compiled to machine code, Android apps are run in a Virtual Machine using byte code and are translated to machine code at the time they are run.

Comment: Oh ! I really wish we could do that... Anyway, Thanks for the quick reply !

Comment: And hey, can we convert ARM binaries to i386 binaries ? The AppStore should convert i386 to ARM before Uploading it to the AppStore (For which you pay $99 for membership)

Comment: No that is not possible, unless you want to recode the app from assembly code.

Comment: Thanks, Seems like I have to buy an iPhone :\

Comment: And I am quite sure you can run Android as an virtual OS in VMWare and use Android Apps in AppMarket?

Comment: If you are planning to develop iOS apps, you should. You can't really test apps on the iPhone simulator alone. Since the simulator is much more powerfull then a real device because it using you Mac's hardware.  Also some things, like push notifications can only be tested on a device. If you don't want to buy an iPhone an iPod Touch could alos be used of development.

Comment: Don't know for sure, since that is not the question asked and I'm not an Android developer.

Comment: @c.adhityaa: you should really start accepting answers here on SO, rckoenes' answer is really helpful, you should accept his answer by clicking the tick mark next to his answer.

Comment: I try to, I am on an iPad and just couldn't...he edited and I had to wait...you can't accept an answer in less than 10 minutes

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT possible

The Simulator does not run ARM code, ONLY x86 code. Unless you have the raw source code from Apple, you won't see the App Store on the Simulator.

The app you write you will be able to test in the Simulator by running it directly from Xcode even if you don't have a developer account. To test your app on an actual device, you will need to be apart of the Apple Developer program.

Comment: Too early to answer? Just kidding :) Thanks!